# Javascript Inheritance call behaviour

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Was going through [Mozilla's Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) and came across this simple relationship.

```
function Employee() {
   this.name = "";
   this.dept = "general";
}

function Manager() {
  Employee.call(this);
  this.reports = [];
}
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
```

Apparantly, this forms a inheritance-like relationship from the Employee to the Manager.

Two questions here, Not sure what and why `Employee.call(this);` is there and
instead of assigning the object to `Employee.prototype` it is assigned to `Manager.prototype`. My thoughts were that Manager is inheriting from Employee, not vice versa. Perhaps this is the concept of the prototype chain where it really means both objects can grab properties from each other?

Would like some clarification.

Comment: Manager will inherit Employee class's properties and will also have its own properties/methods. However Employee class won't inherit Manager's properties though.

Comment: "*instead of assigning the object to `Employee.prototype`*" - which object?

Comment: @Bergi `Employee.prototype = Object.create(Manager.prototype);`

Comment: @Aaron yes, that sets the employees' prototype to an object inheriting from the managers' prototype.

Comment: @Bergi My initial thought looking at the code was that since Manager inherits from Employee, employee's prototype should have a Manager object. The code I expected was the one given above.

Comment: @Aaron: Oops, I missed that you swapped `Employee` with `Manager` there. Right. But no, employee's prototype should not "have a manager object". The `Employee` class doesn't care which subclasses are extending it, and it won't hold references to them. If managers are inheriting from employees, then the prototype chain link goes from `Manager.prototype` to `Employee.prototype`, not the other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Employee.call(this)` is like calling `Employee()`, but instead of using it to create a new object, it instead modifies the current `Manager`. In this example, it sets `name` and `dept` in the `Manager`.
2. This statement:

   ```
   Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
   ```

   means that any attributes set like `Employee.prototype.x = val` will also be available in `Manager.prototype`; however if you override them in `Manager.prototype`, they will be overriden.
   You should also run `Manager.prototype.constructor = Manager` to make that property correct.

Comment: Is it okay to think of `Employee.call(this)` as `super()` in Java?

Comment: I think it’s similar. (I don’t know Java though).

Comment: @Aaron: Yes, that's exactly what it does. It calls the parent constructor on the child instance to create and initialise the parent properties.

Comment: @JF: `Object.create` does not copy anything.

Comment: Is JF's answer wrong? His explanation was extremely clear to me. Not understanding the downvotes.

Comment: @JF Yes, thanks. You might make it even better by replacing the confusing "in the current context" with "on the current instance".

Comment: @JF `Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);` Without this line, any attributes added in some fashion like `Employee.prototype.x = val` Won't be present available for Manager? What if attributes are set without the prototype reference, as in `Employee.id = ...`?

Comment: Attributes like `Employee.prototype.x = val` won’t be available without that line. Either way, “class attributes” like `Employee.id` will have to be manually copied.

Comment: @JF So only time it brings in the class attributes is during the initial call when `Employee.call(this);` is made? But assigning prototypes can allow us to add attributes dynamically-?(assuming)

Comment: Class attributes are never copied. Maybe you’re confusing class attributes (`Employee.id = 2`) and instance attributes (`var employee = new Employee(); employee.id = 2`). They’re in different namespaces.

Comment: How is `this.name = "";`  and `this.dept = "general";` brought in to Manager? I know that `Employee.call(this);` does it, but how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121661/discussion-between-j-f-and-aaron)